# abstract description of the topology on a real vector space where the open sets are those whose algebraic interior are themselves

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

Let $V$ be a real vector space. Given a subset $A \subseteq V$, say that a point $x \in A$ lies in the *algebraic interior* of A if every affine line $\ell$ that pass through $x$ has the property that $x \in (\ell \cap B)^\circ$. Here $\ell \cap B$ is a line segment and $(\ell \cap B)^\circ$ denotes its interior in the usual sense.

Thus, we can define a topology on $V$, where a subset $U \subseteq V$ is *open* if the algebraic interior of $U$ is $U$ itself.

I have a suspicion this topology is the coarsest topology such that every linear function on $V$ is a continuous map. Is my suspicion true?

Comment: It feels weird that your definition of relative interior for the set $\{ x \}$ is empty and not $\{ x\}$ itself. Well maybe that depends on the "usual sense" in which $(\ell\cap B)^\circ$ is defined.

Comment: For any map $f : X \to Y$ where $Y$ is a topological space, $f$ will be continuous under the trivial (aka indescrete) topology on $X$. Thus the coarsest topology on $V$ under which all linear functions are continuous will be the trivial topology.

Comment: If $Y = {a, b}$ is a two-point space with the discrete topology, and $f$ is surjective, then $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ should both be open nonempty subsets of $X$, so one of them is a proper nonempty open subset of $X$, contradicting $X$ having the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Dear P. Quinton, the interior of $\{x\}$ is $\{x\}$ itself. Given a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the interior of $\{c\}$ is $\{c\}$ with the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: not necessarily